# XNA MediaPlayer loading music timing

Tags: xna, loading, playback

I load music with the following code in my load content function:

```
song = Content.Load<Song>("music/game");
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = false;
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

nothing strange there, but each round in my game is 2 minutes long and should sync up with the music (that is 2 minutes long) but the music ends betweem 2-4s early. This wouldn't be a problem if it was always the same time.

My guess is that it has something to do with load times? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is move the `Content.Load<Song>` to Load method and check if it is playing in the update, and if not, play. Eg,

```
public void LoadContent(ConentManager content)
{
    song = content.Load<Song>("music/game");
    gameSongStartedPlaying = false; // this variable to hold if you have starting playing this song already
    MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = false;
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped && !gameSongStartedPlaying)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        gameSongStartedPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

This should start playing the song on the first pass of the Update method rather than in the Loading phase where the song is 'playing' while all resources after `Content.Load<Song>` are still loading (this would be the reason your song finishes early).

Comment: Part of the problems I'm having is that my timer seems to be running incorrect, I'll might try and use the xna stopwatch instead. But  having used your code above acounted for the loading part of the problem :) since the timing error seem a bit more constant now.